# ListView shows no Feedback

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I stumbled about a strange problem with ListViews.

In the emulator the ListView shows no feedback, when an item is pressed for selection. I think I have seen that in the real thing, but I am not sure. I would expect that the list item gets selected (darker background) when it is pressed, so that the user can see, which item he pressed.

Do I have to code that?

RG

After seeing the comments, I tried the following:

I created a file res/color/backgroundstate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="#888"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#888"/>
    <item android:color="#eee"/>
</selector>
```

Then I use this in listitem.xml as a background color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/helptextcolor"
    android:background="@color/backgroundstate"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

When I display the ListView with

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listitem,names);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);
    LV.invalidate();
```

the program crashes.

There are three exceptions connected with this. But the problem seems to be the last one XMLPullParserException:

```
<item> tag needs a drawable.
```

Now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<item>` indeed needs a drawable, not a color. You need a color drawable for that, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#FFFF0000" />
</shape>
```

...and then put that into your item list.
Furthermore, this is a drawable and as such, it has to be in a `/res/drawable-*` directory, not in the `/res/color/` directory.

To sum it up:

- (optional) put your colors in the /res/values/color.xml file with a name
- Create two shape drawables in xml, in the /res/drawable directory, one for the neutral color, one for the pressed color, in the fashion shown above
- Create a state list drawable like you did, but in the /res/drawable directory
- Use that as the background of your list item

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It's not that you have to code it, but you have to not disable it.

If you use custom views to display your list items, you have to put a drawable that allows your view to give feedback when it is selected. For example, a plainbitmap does not.

The easiest way to do this is to create a state list drawable, like this :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList
A listview entry will behave like the button described in the example. If your background drawable includes a state_pressed drawable, it should be displayed when the list entry is pressed.

Comment: My ListItems are TextViews. Or better to say, I use a layout for the items, which is a simple TextView, and an ArrayAdapter for the ListView pointing to that layout. So, how can I highlight a TextView?

Comment: You can put a State list drawable as a background to your textview. The highlight feature of state list backgrounds is not limited to buttons, in fact it works for any view.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sounds like a bit of an overkill, and a performance break. I just discovered that R.layout.simple_list_item_1 does the job. But I cannot use its colors and font size.

Comment: I tried a color state list, but it works only for drawables. I give up for the moment, since I do not want to make code with background images just to get two colors.

Comment: A color state list works. Just put it as the background of your view, that's what a drawable is for. As for performance, if you don't put a background, the framework will put the default background for you. It's not faster.

Comment: I tried that and got an exception. Maybe I should post the code I used. In short: I made a color state list, and used it in the android:background tag of the TextView inside my listitem.xml file. When the list is displayed, the program crashes.

Comment: I posted the code into the original question. Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

See here: http://androidjava.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/listview-and-color-states/